# Accessing Custom Views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am creating an app where almost all the views have the same background and same set of buttons which commit the same action.so I am creating a custom view with the same background and buttons.

```
customView.h

@interface BMBackGroundView : UIView{

}

@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIButton *closeButton;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIButton *menuButton;
```

customView.m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];

    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(104, 36, 275, 33)];
    [self addSubview:self.imageView];


    CGRect frameForCloseButton = CGRectMake(44, 0, 48, 44);
    CGRect frameForMenuButton = CGRectMake(382, 0, 48, 44);

    self.closeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.closeButton setFrame:frameForCloseButton];
    [self.closeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(close:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:self.closeButton];

    self.menuButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.menuButton setFrame:frameForMenuButton];
    [self.menuButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.menuButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:self.menuButton];

}
    return self;
}

-(void)close{
NSLog(@"close button pressed");
}

-(void)showMenu:(id)sender{
     NSLog(@"menu button pressed");

}
```

I am able to get the custom view in the viewController but I want to access navigation controller in both the methods which i am not able to do and I am not able to access the UI elements of the custom View in viewControllers.

In close and showMenu Method.I want

```
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and in ViewController.m where I am getting this Custom View I want to hide One of the Buttons.

```
-(void)loadView{
UIView *learnMoreView = [BMBackGroundView new];
self.view = learnMoreView;

learnMoreView.uielementOfCustomView //which i am not able to access    


[learnMoreView release];

}
```

Note:I am not using Interface Builder

Comment: clarify your question. Where do you want Navigation Controller? And how your using this subclasses uiview.

Comment: You need to make sure that your UI elements are properties of your custom view

Comment: yes i have declared them in customView.h

Comment: "which i am not able to access" -- what happens? Do you get nil if you log learnMoreView.uielementOfCustomView

Comment: @rdelmer I am getting an error property not found on object of type UIView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in this line of code

```
//this is completely wrong 
UIView *learnMoreView = [BMBackGroundView new];
```

your are creating new instance of UIView. You are supposed to create a new instance of BMBackGroundView.

Your code should be

```
BMBackGroundView *learnMoreView = [BMBackGroundView new];
```

This should work. And also make sure that in customView .m

```
@synthesize closeButton, imageView, menuButton;
```

And keep following in the mind while accessing element from other class...

here's what you have to do... Any element you want to access from other class you have to make them public

```
          @interface BMBackGroundView :UIView{
        //Define only private variable here        
        UIButton * closeButton;
        //If you have define closeButton here please delete it, 
    //don't define same variable as public and private... 


}
```

//define all public variable like below that you like to access from other class

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *close Button;
```

I hope this will help... If it did not, please share you .h file.... it will be easy to tell what is going wrong...

Comment: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

interface BMBackGroundView : UIView{
    
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIButton *closeButton;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIButton *menuButton;



@end

Comment: with BMBackGroundView *learnMoreView = [BMBackGroundView new];

Comment: I have edited my answer... read my answer again... mistake you  did in your code is creating a instance of UIView... you should create a instance of BMBackGroundView which is your custom view...

Comment: and do u have any idea how to access the navigation controller from the customView??

Comment: yes.. you can do that you have to make custom init method..in that method you can pass the whole navigation controller. For ex. in your case -(id)initWithRootViewController(ViewController*); this method you  have to declare in custom view. while initializing in view controller...your code should be like.....BMBackGroundView *learnMoreView = [[BMBackGroundView alloc] initWithRootViewController:self]; .... it is kind of tricky. Let me know if you did not get it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a uiview element in xib and change its class to custom view class name. Then you will be able to access the instances from the custom view class.

Or instead of creating an object of uiview type create object like

```
Customview * newView = [customview new];
```

I tried this and i am able to access it. You are doing something wrong. Make sure you written accessor methods properly for the close and menu button.

```
-(void)loadView

{ 

     BKCCustomView *learnMoreView = [BKCCustomView new]; 

     self.view = learnMoreView; 

      //learnMoreView.uielementOfCustomView //which i am not able to access 

      [learnMoreView.menuButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]]; //i am able to access it 
    [learnMoreView release]; 
    }
```

Comment: You seem to have posted a question in the answer box. Please edit to answer the question, or delete this.

Comment: i want to access the custom views uielements from uiviewcontroller

Comment: yes i am doing it but still i am not able to get access and also i am not using interface builder.please check my updated question

Comment: I tried this and i am able to access it. You are doing something wrong. Make sure you written accessor methods properly for the close and menu button.-(void)loadView{
    BKCCustomView *learnMoreView = [BKCCustomView new];
    self.view = learnMoreView;
    
    //learnMoreView.uielementOfCustomView //which i am not able to access
    
    [learnMoreView.menuButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]]; //i am able to access it
    //[learnMoreView release];
    
}